# Plotting only stat_smooth without original ggplot2 data

Tags: r, ggplot2

I plot data with ggplot, and I wanted to see the smoothed lines using stat_smooth.
But now I would like to only plot the smoothed lines (somehow extract it), without the original ggplot.
Do you think it's possible?

Here is my code :

```
Graph <- ggplot(data=Forecasttemp, aes(x=Price.date, y=Price, colour=Group)) + geom_line() + scale_colour_hue(guide = "none")
Graph <- Graph + stat_smooth(se = FALSE,  aes(fill = Group)) + scale_colour_hue(guide = "none")
```

Comment: Maybe I understand you're question wrong, but you can just remove the geom_line()?   ggplot(data=Forecasttemp, aes(x=Price.date, y=Price, colour=Group)) + 
  scale_colour_hue(guide = "none")+ 
  stat_smooth(se = FALSE,  aes(fill = Group))

Comment: Can you please provide a reproducible example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to plot only the smoothed lines without original sample points, you can simply omit geom_line(), thus resulting in:

```
Graph <- ggplot(data=Forecasttemp, aes(x=Price.date, y=Price, colour=Group)) +
         stat_smooth(se = FALSE,  aes(fill = Group)) + 
         scale_colour_hue(guide = "none")
```

Unfortunately I can not try this due to the lack of a reproducible example, but I make a try with an R base dataset and it worked:

```
library(ggplot2)
data(iris)
g1 <- ggplot(data=iris, aes(x=Sepal.Length, y=Petal.Length, colour=Species)) + 
      scale_colour_hue(guide = "none") + geom_smooth()
g1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! As I didn't want the grey buffer around the smoothes line I wrote :
Graph <- ggplot(data=Forecasttemp, aes(x=Price.date, y=Price, colour=Group)) + geom_smooth(se = FALSE,  aes(fill = Group)) + scale_colour_hue(guide = "none")
It's great, thank you!